# list all records in table php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have gone through all the tutorials to no satisfaction and even mix things up to see if it can work but northing works.

```
    <?
require( '../connect_db.php' ) ;

      echo '<h1>List All Customers</h1> ' ;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER";
 $result= mysqli_num_rows($dbc,$query)
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

$clientid=mysql_result($result,"clientid");
$inital=mysql_result($result,"inital");
$firstname=mysql_result($result,"firstname");
$lastname=mysql_result($result,"lastname");
$mobile=mysql_result($result,"mobile");
$landline=mysql_result($result,"landline");
$email=mysql_result($result,"email");
$address=mysql_result($result,"address");
$postcode=mysql_result($result,"postcode");

echo '<table class="table table-hover">
<caption>List All Customers from Customer Table</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>Inital</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Landline</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Post Code</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $clientid; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $inital; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $mobile; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $landline; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $address; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $postcode; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>'

} else {'<p>There are currently no customers on the system.</p>';}
?>
```

Though non of it works, I need help in a simple method of displaying the table records and styling them so they are easy to read. I just need to know what to use as I have referred to the manual that only brings back the first id's or just 'show table' that only shows the tables of database but when i try show records it doesn't work so I know it can't be that easy!

Please can you help?

Comment: are you giving any error on your browser?

Comment: also you are trying nested <?php ... ?> seperate them correctly.

Comment: You'll need to loop through all the results to list them. Your code will only show a single result.

Comment: hakiko and Phil thank you for your replies. Noted. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using both `mysqli` and `mysql` functions. You can't do that. You must choose one or the other. In fact, [mysql functions are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks John for taking the time to reply, Yes I do know that MySQL is becoming depreciated but I choose to use MySQLi as my question states but i was getting desperate to make it work so I tried mixing MySQL with MySQLi I know that was not good and thanks for making it clear for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
 $result= mysqli_num_rows($dbc,$query)
```

should be

```
 $result= mysqli_num_rows($dbc,$query);
```

Comment: woops forgot this ; and thanks for pointing that out Tucker :)

Answer (score 0):

A really nice example of how to do this can be found at [this link](http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php)

Right now you are attempting to put all values into one cell. The example will show you how to step through the records and put one value into each cell, so they stay aligned etc. of course the points others made about syntax errors, not using MySQL, etc, are all good - I am not going to repeat them.

Comment: Thanks Floris for you reply and will looks into it. :)